# A question on econometrics

Tags: statistics

$E_y E_x [y-x'b_0 ]^2=E_{(y,x)}[{y-E[y│x]}]^2+E_{(y,x)}[{E[y│x]-x'b_0}]^2$

This appears in Greene’s econometrics textbook, and I don’t know how the conditional expectations can be decomposed in this way.

Also, if $y’y-b’X’y-y’Xb+b’X’Xb=y’y-2y’Xb+b’X’Xb$, then are the matrices $b$, $X$ and $y$ all symmetric (square) matrices?

Answer

Request

Comment: Please type your question using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot comment on your first question, because I am not familiar with the notation (the subscripts are confusing me). I am also not sure which Greene's text you are using.

--

As for your second question, there is no need for **b**, **X**, and **y** to be symmetric. In regression analysis, **b** is a px1 vector, **y** is an nx1 vector, and **X** is an nxp matrix. Here, p is the number of parameters needing to be estimated (usually one more than the number of independent variables).

If you follow the matrix dimensions for the equation you give, you will find that the multiplications and additions work with no problems; the matrices are appropriately commensurate. Note that **y′y − b′X′y − y′Xb + b′X′Xb** is a 1x1 matrix, as is **y′y − 2y′Xb + b′X′Xb**.